# Understanding pycharm commit log for hard reset before incorrect merge

Tags: python, git, github, pycharm

Here is a tree of the situation

[image]

Everything up to the Bokeh branch split is fine. The "Works with python3 and ubunutu" commit is the commit I want to hard reset the head to for the Bokeh branch.

I cant switch to the Bokeh branch because the [Git Branches popup](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/accessing-git-branches-popup-menu.html) no longers has a checkout option. The branch I'm on is apparently "Merging master" as you can see in the bottom right

I made an incorrect merge. I ultimately want to checkout the "Works with python3 and ubunutu" revision but pycharm wont allow me until merge conflicts are resolved. I need to look at this revision so as to compare results against code from the most recent commit.

Answer (score 1):

You have a merge commit in progress, if you don't want it you should abort your merge.

`git merge --abort`

Comment: How do I do this in pycharm?

Comment: I don't think that aborting a git merge is supported in pycharm, I recommend running this command in your terminal (or in pycharm's built-in terminal plugin if you have it enabled). That being said, you can achieve something similar with `git reset --hard HEAD`, which pycharm does support: go to `VCS > Git > Reset HEAD` and use a hard reset on HEAD.

Comment: Okay so Alt + F12 opens up the terminal. I did git merge --abort and it worked. I managed to reset the head og the Bokeh branch to where I want, I modifed the code how I want... and now when I try to commit it complains about a merge conflict. Why?